# Method not allowed but code is being re used

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to call an update method from a controller which I have defined all the routes (Once I defined one of their routes, can I define routes with resource?,  I got an error...) by miself, but right know I'm getting an error, even when I have being using the same code from other working route and view.
Could you help me to identify the error?
Thanks in advance.

The route (All others work fine but update).

```
    Route::get('notas/notasGet/', 'NotasController@notasGet')->name('notas.notasGet');
    Route::post('notas/notasPost/', 'NotasController@notasPost')->name('notas.notasPost');
    Route::get('notas/create/', 'NotasController@create')->name('notas.create');
    Route::get('notas/store/', 'NotasController@store')->name('notas.store');
    Route::post('notas/update/{id}', 'NotasController@update')->name('notas.update');
```

Actually I hadn't have success with parameters, but suppose it will come after the call can be done.

The controller (the tipic resorce)

```
public function update(Request $request, Nota $nota)
{
    //
}
```

The view

```
            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
                <h1 class="h5">Nota de venta</h1>
                <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
                  <div class="btn-group mr-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Exportar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="border-bottom">

                        <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1 ">

                          <form method="post" action="{{ route('notas.update',[$nota->idNota]) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">


                              <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox" value="true"> Pagada
                                </label>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                                <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="usuario">
                                  <option value="">Selecciona...</option>
                                  <option>United States</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  Please select a valid country.
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <p>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="strNota">Comentarios</label>
                                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="strNota" name="text"></textarea>
                                </div>
                              </p>
                            <p>
                            <hr class="mb-4">

                            <div >

                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Guardar cambios <br> en la venta</button>
                            </div>

                            </p>
                          </form>
                        </div>

                </div>
```

The calling to update came from a call to create, which I post the code here, and is part of the same controller.

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $lockers = null;
    $lockers = Locker::all();
    $eventos = null;
    $eventos = Evento::all();
    $cajaAbierta = Caja::whereRaw('dtmCorte IS NULL')->get()->first();
    $currentTime = Carbon::now('-5:00');
    $cargos = null;
    $cargos = Cargo::all();
    $productos = ProductoServicioEvento::all();

    if($cajaAbierta)
    {
        $nota = Nota::create(
            [
                'idCaja'=>$cajaAbierta->idCaja,
                'idRealiza'=>$cajaAbierta->idUsuario,
                'dtmHoraCargo'=>$currentTime,
            ]
        );

        if($nota)
        {
//                return redirect()->route('grupos.index')->with('success','Grupo creado con éxito');
            return view('notas.create',['lockers'=>$lockers,'eventos'=>$eventos,'nota'=>$nota, 'cargos'=>$cargos,'productos'=>$productos]);
        }
    }
}
```

The test at navigator, when I click the button "Guardar cambios en la venta".

[image]

The error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the `Method` as `PUT` here

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

But you have defined your `Route` as `POST` here

```
Route::post('notas/update/{id}', 'NotasController@update')->name('notas.update');
```

That's the reason for the

> Method Not Allowed Here Exception

Simply change your route to `PUT`

```
Route::put('notas/update/{id}', 'NotasController@update')->name('notas.update');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually this is the right aswer but I couldn't get the check. I undestood that only existed post an get and you do the job with  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">. Thanks again